# Why sleep in an async function is not executed asynchronously

Tags: dart

```dart
void task() async {
  print("working...");
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 4));
  print("done");
}
```

When I run like this:

```dart
task();
task();
task();
```

I got the result:

```dart
working...
done
working...
done
working...
done
```

My expect result was:

```dart
working working working done done done
```

When I changed

```dart
 sleep(Duration(seconds: 4));
```

to

```dart
awiat Dio().get("xxx.xx.xx.xx");
```

It worked as my expect.
Why sleep still stop the main thread even I put it in an async function?
I was confused about how the aysnc works, I throught when a function was marked as async function, It would executed asynchronously if I not use await.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart 2, async functions are executed synchronously until it hits the first await or return. As you have neither in your task() function the code runs synchronously, hits the sleep and pauses for 4 seconds before continuing. If you add await to the sleep, you will get the output you were expecting. However, with sleep being a blocking call there will still be a four second delay between each print of 'working...'.

```
void task() async {
  print("working...");
  await sleep(Duration(seconds: 4));
  print("done");
}
```

There is a useful section on async and await in the Dart docs:

https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: `await sleep()` doesn't really make sense since `sleep` does not return a `Future`.  Adding *any* `await` (e.g. `await null`) would yield execution though.

Comment: @jamesdlin You are right, After I added `await null`, It worked as expect。But the code looks so ugly. When I want put some heavy CPU works to the background task. I must add the `await null` before them, even in async function。why dart design like this...

Answer (score 0):

> Why sleep still stop the main thread even I put it in an async function?

The whole point of `sleep` is to pause execution.  [`sleep`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-io/sleep.html) is a blocking call:

> *Use this with care, as no asynchronous operations can be processed in a isolate while it is blocked in a sleep call.*

You probably want to use [`Future.delayed`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html) in your test instead.

Note that you also must use `await` in your function to *yield* execution and to wait for the `Future` to complete before executing `print("done")`.

Comment: `await Future(() => sleep(Duration(seconds: 4)));`, This worked as my expect. Async function is a function that maybe work in background whether there is an `await xxx` or not, so confused.

Comment: @Field.wei `await Future(() => sleep(Duration(seconds: 4))` has your expected behavior simply by virtue of having an `await`, which yields execution; it doesn't make `sleep()` non-blocking. Be aware that Dart isolates are single-threaded, so using asynchronous functions doesn't inherently do work in the background.