# FutureBuilder has been suspended with future method contains for loop

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future

When I use a future method containing for loop with FutureBuilder, The app UI becomes unable to respond, why?

Future method:

```dart
    Future<bool> processGo() {
    return Future(() {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        // something takes time
        sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));

      }

      return true;
    });
  }
```

UI Builder:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: controller.processGo(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

        return Text("processGo completed");
      },
    );
  }
```

Update:
I got the solution that i want by using `compute` isolate technique

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: compute(controller.processGo, null),
      ...
}
```

resource:
https://blog.logrocket.com/multithreading-flutter-using-dart-isolates/

Comment: Also see [Why sleep in an async function is not executed asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56699199/).  I currently can't add that as a duplicate since it doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

the Future you used has no await and you didn't mark it as asynchronous, so the Future will not wait for anything.

here, try this :

```
Future<bool> processGo() async {
 return Future(() {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    // something takes time
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
  return true;
});
}
```

Comment: it's marked as asynchronous because i returned ```Future()```, but i want to use Sync method into for loop like ```sleep(Duration(seconds: 1))```, don't use ```Future.delayed```, is there a solution for this?

Comment: I got the solution, check question update, Thank you @Gwhyyy