# Async would not run async in Dart

Tags: dart, asynchronous

For loop in fu is only executed after for-loop in main. I thought that both loops would run at the same time?

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  fu();
  for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
    print(x);
    sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }
}

Future<int> fu() async {
  print("start fu");
  await Future.microtask(() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      print(Isolate.current.debugName);
      sleep(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
    print("end fu");
  });
  return (10);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77074495/

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with `sleep` that is documented with the following:

> Sleep for the duration specified in `duration`.
>
> Use this with care, as no asynchronous operations can be processed in a isolate while it is blocked in a sleep call.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.1/dart-io/sleep.html

So, your usage of `sleep` prevents any of your `async` operations from being executed. Try change your code to the following instead:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  fu();
  for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
    print(x);
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }
}

Future<int> fu() async {
  print("start fu");
  await Future.microtask(() async {
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      print(Isolate.current.debugName);
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
    print("end fu");
  });
  return (10);
}
```

This will instead of `sleep` use delayed `Future` objects which it then awaits on. This will allow other `async` events to be executed.

Comment: This works; but got 'main' on Isolate.current.debugName. So, these 2 loops are still executed on the same thread?

Comment: @Jomme Yes. If you want to utilize multiple threads, you need to look into isolates. I recommend reading: https://dart.dev/language/concurrency

Comment: Ok thanks, so it's safe to pass a  simple callback to fu(callbackFunc) to follow progress (and update an indicator)?

Comment: @Jomme I don't understand the problem you are having so can't answer that question. It is also not part of the initial question so I suggest create a new question instead of making this one a longer discussion in the comments.