# Flutter non blocking process

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

Why flutter can not handle non blocking process ?
as far as i know , async methods generated for handle this concept .
for example this code :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: processFile,
                child: Text("File Process"),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: anotherProcess,
                child: Text("Another Process"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static Future<void> processFile() async {
    developer.log("File Process Executed");
    final selectedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false, type: FileType.any);

    if (selectedFile == null) return;

    var fileBytes = selectedFile.files.single.bytes!;

    const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
    var totalSize = fileBytes.length;
    var totalChunks = (totalSize / chunkSize).ceil();

    developer.log("TotalSize:  $totalSize  TotalChunks: $totalChunks");

    final Uint8List byteData = Uint8List.fromList(fileBytes);
    final chunks = List<Uint8List>.generate(
      totalChunks,
      (int index) {
        final start = index * chunkSize;
        final end = start + chunkSize < totalSize ? start + chunkSize : totalSize;
        return byteData.sublist(start, end);
      },
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
      var b64 = base64Encode(chunks[i]);
      sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // only for simulate process 
      developer.log("Process Chunk $i $b64");
    }
  }

  static Future<void> anotherProcess() async {
    developer.log("Another Process Executed");
  }
}
```

I have two method `processFile` and `anotherProcess` .
when i click on `File Process` button  , can not call `Another Process` until file process finished . (Web browser freezed !)
I misunderstood about async functions ? or my code has some problems ?
**Note** : I tested this code on web browser. (i think platform type is not matter about async concept)
**Note** : Also, web browser frozen without sleep. (you can test it)

Comment: See: [Why sleep in an async function is not executed asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56699199/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sleep` function pauses the execution of code for the specified duration, effectively blocking the UI thread, it is causing the problem.

You can try `Future.delayed` instead of `sleep`.

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // Simulate process without blocking UI
```

Comment: no , without sleep also web browser hanging . I can not understand !

Comment: @mah454 If you took out the `sleep` without adding `await Future.delayed(...)`, then `processFile` will never *yield* execution. `processFile` needs to use `await` (which is syntactic sugar for returning a `Future`) to yield execution to the main event loop.